# Find which developer email account is linked firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I am currently working on the old project. I am having the whole working android project but I am not aware which firebase account is my android project linked with. Please help!!

I want to know where I can find the developer email address of the firebase account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about the developer of the project is not exposed on the configuration data that is included in the app. If this was possible, it would actually be a security risk as any user of your app could then find that email address.

If you are the developer yourself, but forgot which email address you used to sign in to the Firebase console, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. If you're not the developer, I'm afraid there's not much they (or any of us) can do.